# Failure handling for Queue Centric work pattern

Tags: azure, message-queue, task-queue, azure-queues

I am planning to use a queue centric design as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/queue-centric-work-pattern) for one of my applications. That essentially consists of using a Azure queue where work requests are queued from the UI. A worker reads from the queue, processes and deletes the message from the queue.

The 'work' done by the worker is within a transaction so if the worker fails before completing, upon restart it again picks up the same message (as it has not be deleted from the queue) and tries to perform the operation again (up to a max number of retries)

**To scale** I could use two methods:

1. **Multiple workers each with a separate queue**. So if I have five workers W1 to W5, I have 5 queues Q1 to Q5 and each worker knows which queue to read from and failure handling is similar as the case with one queue and one worker
2. **One queue and multiple workers**. Here failure/Retry handling here would be more involved and might end up using the 'Invisibility' time in the message queue to make sure no two workers pick up the same job. The invisibility time would have to be calculated to make sure that its enough for the job to complete and yet not be large enough that retries are performed after a long time.

Would like to know if the 1st approach is the correct way to go? What are robust ways of handling failures in the second approach above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off taking approach 2 - a single queue, but with multiple workers.

This is better because:

- The process that delivers messages to the queue only needs to know about a single queue endpoint.  This reduces complexity at this end;
- Scaling the number of workers that are pulling from the queue is now decoupled from any code / configuration changes - you can scale up and down much more easily (and at runtime)

If you are worried about the `visibility`, you can initially choose a default `timespan`, and then if the worker looks like it's taking too long, it can periodically call [UpdateMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.updatemessage.aspx) to update the visibility of the message.

Finally, if your worker timesout and failed to complete processing of the message, it'll be picked up again by some other worker to try again.  You can also use the [DequeueCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage.dequeuecount.aspx) property of the message to manage number of retries.

Answer (score 1):

> Multiple workers each with a separate queue. So if I have five workers
>   W1 to W5, I have 5 queues Q1 to Q5 and each worker knows which queue
>   to read from and failure handling is similar as the case with one
>   queue and one worker

With this approach I see following issues:

- This approach makes your architecture tightly coupled (thus beating the whole purpose of using queues). Because each worker role listens to a dedicated queue, the web application responsible for pushing messages in the queue always need to know how many workers are running. Anytime you scale up or down your worker role, some how you need to tell web application so that it can start pushing messages in appropriate queue.
- If a worker role instance is taken down for whatever reason there's a possibility that some messages may not be processed ever as other worker role instances are working on their dedicated queues.
- There may be a possibility of under utilization/over utilization of worker role instances depending on how web application pushes the messages in the queue.  For optimal utilization, web application should know about the worker role utilization so that it can decide which queue to send message to. This is certainly not a desired thing for a web application to do.

I believe #2 is the correct way to go. @Brendan Green has covered your concerns about #2 in his answer excellently.